# How to speed up column wise operation in MATLAB using bsxfun?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the Square Euclidean Distance between each column from two matrices and store in matrix `D`.

`im_patches` is **81*60840** double

`codebook` is **81*456** double

```
SquareEuclidean = @(x, y) x'*x+y'*y-2*x'*y;

% Get N*K distance matrix D between the N patches extracted
% from the image (im patches) and the K prototypes in the codebook
D=zeros(size(im_patches,2),size(codebook, 2));

for i=1:size(im_patches,2)
    for j=1:size(codebook, 2)
        D(i,j)=SquareEuclidean(im_patches(:,i),codebook(:,j));
    end
end
```

However, this is very inefficient that cost more than 10 minutes in my laptop.

I am wondering is there a better way of using `bsxfun`. So I tried:

```
D2 = bsxfun(@(x,y) x'.*x+y'.*y-2.*x'.*y,im_patches,codebook);
```

which gives an error:

> Error using bsxfun: Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

I think `bsxfun` or `arrayfun` would be a nice way of dealing such problem. But don't know the correct way of doing this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **`bsxfun`** ? yup definitey. `arrayfun`? nops

Comment: Take a look on [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)

Comment: @EBH Thank you for your editing and comments, I will check it out. It seems like a nice solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop can be reduced to:

```
bsxfun(@plus,sum(im_patches.'.^2,2),sum(codebook.^2)-2*im_patches.'*codebook)
```

In MATLAB r2016b there is no need to bsxfun:

```
sum(im_patches.'.^2,2)+sum(codebook.^2)-2*im_patches.'*codebook
```